# Ubuntu 16 add user with all permissions

Tags: ssh, ftp

just wondering how I add a user with the same permissions as the root user? I've tried many things and nothing seems to work.
mainly R/W access the Filezilla. Thanks.

Comment: Can you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1002845/edit) your question and give us commands that you have tried.  Also, what version of Ubuntu 16 are you running?  16.04 or 16.10?  This is important as Ubuntu 16.10 is no longer supported as it is end of life.  Also, what does ssh and ftp have to do with your question?

Comment: in all honesty, I've run too many commands over the past week and can't remember half of them lol

Answer (score 0):

Just add the user to the `/etc/sudoers` file, following the next steps:

1. Open a terminal with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Switch to user root with `su`
3. Edit the sudoers file with `nano /etc/sudoers`(If you don't want to edit the text via terminal, try with `gedit /etc/sudoers`, it's up to you)
4. Whenever you open the file, just search for the followin text: `root    ALL=(ALL) ALL`. Once you detect it, add a column and write below: `username ALL=(ALL) ALL` (Where "username" is the user you want to give the root  permissions)